# Cannot load socket.io.js file when using electron

Tags: jquery, node.js, socket.io, electron

I am trying to make a chat application using Node.js with Electron and Socket.io, but when I try to load `/socket.io/socket.io.js`, I always get the error:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

If I just start the server on port 3000 and put

```
res.sendFile(__dirname+"/index.html");
```

then  socket.io.js can be loaded, but if I use electron and put

```
mainWindow.loadURL("File://"+__dirname+"/index.html");
```

then the it gives me the above mentioned error.

here is the code for my index.js page:

```
const electron = require('electron');
const {app, BrowserWindow} = electron;

app.on('ready', function(){
  var mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1400,
    height: 800
  });

  mainWindow.loadURL("File://"+__dirname+"/index.html");
  mainWindow.toggleDevTools();
});
```

here is my server.js page:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

users = [];
connections = [];

server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, "localhost");
console.log("Server running...");

app.get('/', function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname+"/index.html");
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
  connections.push(socket);
  console.log('Connected: %s sockets connected', connections.length);

  //Disconect
  socket.on('disconnect', function(data){
    connections.splice(connections.indexOf(socket), 1);
    console.log('Disconnected: %s sockets connected', connections.length);
  });

  //Send message
  socket.on('send message', function(data){
    console.log("Message Received");
    io.sockets.emit('new message', data);
  });
});
```

And here is my index.html page:

```
 <html>
  <head>
    <title>Chat Server</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href="./style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chat"></div>
    <form id="info">
      <textarea placeholder="Message" col="50" id="message"></textarea>
      <input type = "submit" value="Send"></input>
    </form>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
    var socket = io.connect();
      $(function(){
        var socket = io.connect();
        var messageForm = $("#info");
        var message = $("#message");
        var chat = $("#chat");

        messageForm.submit(function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          console.log("A message has been submited.");
          socket.emit('send message', message.val());
          message.val(" ");
        });

        socket.on('new message', function(data){
          chat.append("<div class='chat-message'><div class='chat-user'>Max Braun</div><div class='chat-text'>"+data+"</div><div class=''>8/30/1999 at 8:33 PM</div></div>");
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` should also indicate which resource failed to load, so what was it?

Comment: I've had the same issue. In the end I just ended up using `socket.io-client` for my render processes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Teak comment is right , socket io in devlopement mode expose an api route `/socket.io/socket.io.js` at the main root of your application , once you package the app with electron this will not work anymore . so the solution would be to modify the entry point of your socket io client library and replace it by a CDN or a local file that you will include in your app.

so instead of this

```
 <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

you can put this

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.4.8/socket.io.min.js"></script>
```

hope it helps !